# Cannot read exported module on jest react-navigation

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I just migrated from ex-navigation where all my tests worked. I followed the guides, and read the docs. The app is completely functional, but I need to get the tests working. Everything looks just fine, but the error won't let me run none of my tests. Seems to be an error on transpile time, where the module is undefined. However I cannot even log the value of the imported packages.

[image: screen shot 2017-04-23 at 17 00 00]

This is the code that throws:

```
import { AppNavigator } from '../AppNavigator'

/*
** navigation
*/
export function navigation (state, action) {
  const nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state)
  return { ...state, ...nextState}
}
```

This is how I export AppNavigator:

```
/**
* @providesModule %AppNavigator
* @flow
*/
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation'

import { CloudAccount } from './containers/integrations/CloudAccount'
import * as Containers from './containers'

const routes = {
  Init: {
    screen: Containers.Init,
  },
  CloudAccount: {
    screen: CloudAccount,
  },
}

Object.keys(Containers).forEach(key => {
  routes[key] = {
    screen: Containers[key],
  }
})

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(routes, {
  headerMode: 'screen',
  navigationOptions: {
    gesturesEnabled: false,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      elevation: 1,
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    headerBackTitle: null,
  },
  cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
})
```

This is my jest config:

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation)"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "app/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/tasks/**",
      "!**/meta/**",
      "!**/ios/**",
      "!**/app/lib/**"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "meta/coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^React$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react"
    }
  },
```

I already removed node_modules, reinstalled, removed watchman and cleaned cachés. Does anyone have a clue?